# CFT with defect: Real OPE coefficients in the bulk-defect expansion?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ising-model

I am studying the article by Gaiotto, Mazac and Paulos from 2013 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.5078v2.pdf , and I am wondering whether the OPE coefficients in the bulk-defect expansion (2.6) are real-valued. If there would be no defect, the OPE coefficients would be real-valued in order to have unitarity, but this does not seem to be the case in this paper. See for example (3.9) and (3.18). It would be nice to hear an argument for why these coefficients do not need to be real-valued.